# Why Elasticsearch 5.3.3 crashing when trying to test a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have a Rails application which uses Elasticsearch 5.3.3 on an Ubuntu server 14. Before I run the test command I checked if Elasticsearch is running with CURL command. The command worked. Then I run the command for the test and I see the failure for elastic search:

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)
```

So I checked again the service and I saw was not running anymore. 
Seems Elasticsearch is stopping when I run the test and cannot figure out the reason.

I tried to reinstall the 5.3.3 version and get the same result. 
Before the test, in Rails the service is running after no anymore.

Comment: Coud you post the output of tail -n50 /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log ?

Comment: @Lupanoide This is the output https://pastebin.com/NmGCSjCf

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I just had the problem , although everything was working fine a few days ago